Ubuntu 24.04 sound does not configure or work with motherboard line in/out
I've created a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 on a new system using a MSI MAG B650 Tomahawk mobo.
I use a Senheiser headset so I connected them to the mobo rear mic/line connections as per the mobo diagram.
The sound did not work. The sound settings listed my webcam and monitor speakers along with 'USB Audio'. It did not list the Realtek line out or mic in which is what I expected to see and use.
I got the sound sorta working by deleting ~/.local/share/wireplumber files and rebooting per trawling some of posts by the many people with 24.04 sound problems. However the levels are not right and its labelled USB Audio and playing to the line out which is not right.
The microphone works on the usb webcam but the headset mic (with its handy mute and sensitivity) is not available as an input.
I feel that I should be able to see the relevant output and input devices in the sound settings and that I should be able to connect them.
The motherboard states that its Audio is using Realteck ALC4080 codec, 7.1 Channel USB High Performance Audio, Supports S/PDIF output.
How can I proceed? Is there some additional or updated driver I need to install?

Similar situation here. The front panel audio and the small USB speakers and also the back panel mic is all working. But not the back panel audio (works in win11). I don't seem to find the back panel audio as an output option.
Ubuntu 24.04 full updates

I'm still stuck but I have re-stated my problem given my investigations so far: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1521765/how-can-i-adjust-the-base-volume-for-a-microphone-in-ubuntu-24-04
