How can I adjust the "Base Volume" for a microphone in Ubuntu 24.04?
"Base Volume" not "Volume"!
There are quite a few people with similar (the same?) problems posting here, and the answers generally point to adjusting the "Volume" which doesn't help.
My headset microphone is actually working. I spent some time thinking it wasn't because even a shout doesn't register. However, tapping the microphone with my fingernail shows a blip in the sound settings panel. It is working, it is just much, much too quiet.
Using pactl list sources, I can see that there are two volumes relating to the micropone:
Source #187
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback
    Description: Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A) Mono
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s16le 1ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: mono
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: mono: 100000 / 153% / 11.01 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 27111 /  41% / -23.00 dB

The Base Volume is clearly much too low. I've tried all manner of tools but they only adjust the "Volume" and not the "Base Volume". How can I adjust the Base Volume to make my microphone useable?
I can adjust the normal volume up to 153% (further increases leave it capped at this value) which is not enough to hear anything with normal use.
Note that Ubuntu 24.04 uses pipewire and not pulseaudio, and I've not found a way to alter the base volume using alsamixer.

Please edit your question to clearly explain how your base volume issue is different from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349491/setting-the-base-volume-level-on-a-pulseaudio-device

Thanks to the link to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349491/setting-the-base-volume-level-on-a-pulseaudio-device in the comment on my question:
I was able to find the offending volume control in alsamixer and to turn it up. It is labelled as 'MM' on the far right of the card volume levels.
